# Build/run iOS Xcode project from Terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, testing, terminal

I want to build a Xcode project from Terminal and then run it as required, also from Terminal.

I have been looking for a way to do this for a while now but only managed to find a method which works for the iPhone Simulator, not for the actual device it self.

Is this even possible? The reason I want to a Xcode project on a device from Terminal is because the application runs a series of automated tests and I would prefer to automate this process using a bash script.

Thanks

Answer (score 20):

To build your xcode project from the command line using a bash script use:

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -target TargetYouWantToBuild -configuration Debug
```

Look at the man page for xcodebuild for more options.

We do this for our unit test suite target, and we use GHUnit.

This is the section of our build script for running the tests:

```
export GHUNIT_CLI=1
export WRITE_JUNIT_XML=1
clean
echo "Building Bamboo GHUnit Tests..."
OUTPUT=`/usr/bin/xcodebuild -target BambooAutomatedUnitTest -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator4.3 build`
RESULT=`echo "$OUTPUT" | grep "\\*\\* BUILD "`
if [ "$RESULT" != "** BUILD SUCCEEDED **" ]
then
    echo "$OUTPUT"
    exit 1
fi
echo "${RESULT}\n"
```

Comment: Lets say I have two xcode (xcode4 and xcode5 in the same machine)
Can I say use that one (not the xcode in the applications but in the desktop) from command line? is it possible?

Comment: Possibly... When you install Xcode it will put the scripts into /usr/bin but you can run any version of /usr/bin/xcodebuild, so it could be /Users/dave/Desktop/Xcode/xcodebuild

Comment: yea I have tried that, but it does not find the command (it seems Windowsian! way of seeing the problem) 
So I have asked the question and someone answered, the solution is to use "xcode-select --switch" command as explained in here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040472/building-xcode-project-in-terminal-choosing-another-xcode/22040547?noredirect=1#22040547