# How to generate xcode project through terminal?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying generate xcode project through terminal. I have a idea of making a command line utility similar to the rails setup application. When we create xcode project and the hierarchy that is generated automatically. I want the same hierarchy to be created through command line. I find some way like cmake command. This command is used for creating xcode project but when i fired that command on my terminal, it won't work.

Comment: You can use this a starting point and customise it to your needs https://github.com/thoughtbot/liftoff

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486326/build-run-ios-xcode-project-from-terminal Try To do